# fastapi pagination on distinct column

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I want to the get data of distinct records of paginated data, I'm following the fastapi pagination doc [here](https://uriyyo-fastapi-pagination.netlify.app/) .
In the below code snippet

```
from sqlalchemy import select
from fastapi_pagination.ext.sqlalchemy import paginate


@app.get('/users', response_model=Page[UserBase])
def get_users(db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    return paginate(db, select(distinct(User.first_name)).order_by(User.created_at)) # This returns null data distinct records

    # return paginate(db, select(User).order_by(User.created_at)) # This provides correct data without distinct
```

my user model

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, EmailStr
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Boolean
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

# SQLAlchemy table definition
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    first_name = Column(String(50))
    last_name = Column(String(50))
    email = Column(String(100), unique=True, index=True)
    active = Column(Boolean, default=True)

# Pydantic model schema
class UserBase(BaseModel):
    first_name: str
    last_name: str
    email: EmailStr
    active: bool
```

the response

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "first_name": null,
      "last_name": null,
      "email": null,
      "active": null,
      
    },
   {
      "first_name": null,
      "last_name": null,
      "email": null,
      "active": null,
      
    }
  ],
  "total": 2,
  "page": 1,
  "size": 1,
  "pages": 0
}
```

Any suggestion, that i'm doing wrong in getting the unique data records in my paginated data?

Comment: I want specifically only unique first_names (sql generated is correct) , this I would use for filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by adding transformer

```
from sqlalchemy import select
from fastapi_pagination.ext.sqlalchemy import paginate


@app.get('/users', response_model=Page[UserBase])
def get_users(db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
     return paginate(
            db_session,
            select(distinct(User.first_name)),
            transformer=lambda items: [{"first_name": first_name} for first_name in items],
        )

    # return paginate(db, select(distinct(User.first_name)).order_by(User.created_at)) # This returns null data distinct records

    # return paginate(db, select(User).order_by(User.created_at)) # This provides correct data without distinct
```